# Migration from English.SE

Tags: discussion

It has been [suggested on the English Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/how-does-should-english-se-regard-linguistics-se) that questions regarding linguistic topics there should be copied to Linguistics.SE and then closed on EL&U. Now that Linguistics.SE has been launched, what are the plans? How are these tasks normally carried out? Are moderators in charge of this task or is it done on a volunteer base? if so, I can volunteer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This wont happen too often while in beta. Once the site graduates, there will very likely be a migration path set up, based on need. However, I don't think that one should be concerning themselves about carrying out some massive migration plan so early. Focus your efforts on building this community, and when we've built this one, then we can look at pulling stuff from other communities.

During public beta, it's rather inadvisable migrate too many question *into* this site. It is much more beneficial generate questions from *within* the community, than to rely on castoff question from another community. Many of those questions have been asked and answered, and you will not reap the benefits of participation from inheriting those questions here.

Once things get smoothed out, especially post-graduation, it's very likely there will be a migration path setup, based on how many questions may need to be moved. In the meantime, if you feel there is a **very strong need** to migrate a question, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: There are a number of such questions and most every one has a comment to that effect, plus a link to the area51 site to commit to linguistics.SE. Unfortunately, the search procedure only works on question and answer text, __not comments__. Is there some easy way to find all questions which involve such a link?

Comment: I found out about the EL&U the other day and tried to register there, but they didn't know about my registration here. And, I have to say, the level of grammar knowledge and discussion there is pretty abysmal. I'd like to continue commenting on it -- it's been one of my professional concerns for decades (http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue) -- but I don't know whether it's worth it, if they are turning their back on English syntax and concentrating on "correctness" and Greek names for rhetorical figures.

Comment: @waiwai933 Thanks. I don't want to post on meta.english, really, until I have a better idea what's what there. I'd prefer to answer questions about English language and usage, but most of what I see is punctuation and vague handwaving, and if that's what's apropos, I don't think I'd be. I can't tell until I answer questions and see whether people respond, and I can't answer questions until I get registered properly. That's all.

Ah! I appear to be registered and recognized now. Thank you.