# How to set up migration path and should we?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migration from English.SE](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/migration-from-english-se)

As title. Grace Note (from StackExchange) [noted here](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/migration-from-english-se) that it is not a good idea to do it early and too much, but I think we can start doing it now (only for some questions that obviously are good questions here). What do you think guys, and how can it be set up?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink

Comment: The question you linked is a statement of policy and procedure. I updated it a bit to bring it up to your current progress. But you are essentially asking the same question. If you have a response, please contribute it to *that* thread rather than splitting the conversation. Thanks.